# Trying to execute a bash script in NASM

Tags: bash, assembly, nasm

Hello I am quite a beginner in nasm. I am trying to write a program that executes a script, that takes one argument, with /bin/bash.

```
 SECTION .data
      command db '/bin/bash', 0
      script  db 'path/to/script', 0
      script_arg db 'my_arg', 0
      arguments dd command
                dd script  ; arguments to pass to commandline, in this case just the path to the script
                dd script_arg
                dd  0

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

    mov edx, 0 ; no environment variables are being used
    mov ecx, arguments ; array of pointers has to be passed
    mov ebx, command    ; bash
    mov eax, 11   ; invoke SYS_EXECVE 
    int     80h
```

The code above just executes the script with bash but does not add any arguments to the script itself. I tried to pass it as an additional argument but that does nothing. If I add the argument to the path to script string (path/to/script arg1) it breaks the terminal (color theme is set to just white text) and other than that does nothing.

Also what would be the easiest way of changing the contents of the arguments pointer array? How would I define that in .bss section and change its contents while the program is running? At least a point to the documentation about that would be nice...

Comment: It's unclear what you tried. Did you put a `dd script_arg` in the `arguments` array before the terminating `dd 0`?

Comment: yes I exactly did that and as the script argument is not a valid path to script or anything that can be executed with bash nothing is executed.

Comment: Passing a null environment pointer is probably not going to work, since the script will try to call programs that are found via `$PATH`. If you don't want to add any environment variables, you should just copy the current process's `env` pointer.'

Comment: It would probably be easier if you called `execl()` or `execv()`.

Comment: `bash path/to/script myarg` should run `script` with an arg.  Is that not happening (e.g. because you replaced `script` with `script_arg` instead of adding another `dd` entry to the `char *argv[]` array), or is your script broken and trying to use `myarg` as a command?  Use `strace ./a.out` to see the execve system call you actually make, and/or put a `set -x` in your script to see what commands run in it.

Comment: Note that you'll need multiple array entries if you want multiple args, unless your script can parse multiple options as part of a single arg, like `ls -lhacrt` or whatever.  But yeah you could reserve some space in the BSS and have an arg that points to it, so you can store whatever string bytes you want.  Or `push` some string data onto the stack and store a pointer to it into your argv array.  (It would have to be in `.data` or `.bss` itself for that to work.)

Comment: Yeah in the state as it is right now when I run the program nothing happens at all, no output or error message, the extra argument in pointer array does not get recognized I think.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere then. Works fine here.

Comment: Well I rewrote it entirely and now when I run the program I get a bash error message: my_arg: no such file or directory

Comment: Omg forget what I said, I was missing the pointer labeled command the in the array of pointers the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I put in run-bash.asm :

```
SECTION .data
      command db '/bin/bash', 0
      script  db './test.sh', 0
      script_arg db 'my_arg', 0
      arguments dd command
                dd script  ; arguments to pass to commandline, in this case just the path to the script
                dd script_arg
                dd  0

SECTION .text
global  _start

_start:

    mov edx, 0 ; no environment variables are being used
    mov ecx, arguments ; array of pointers has to be passed
    mov ebx, command    ; bash
    mov eax, 11   ; invoke SYS_EXECVE 
    int     80h
```

And put in test.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
echo "First argument is : $1"
```

The run it with :

```
nasm -f elf run-bash.asm
ld -m elf_i386 run-bash.o -o run-bash
chmod +x run-bash
./run-bash
# Output : 
# First argument is : my_arg
```

Comment: yeah this concept does work, the issue lied in my fatigue and spaghetti code :)